# Why didn't Hartley die instantly after she picked Obelisk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Obelisk kills a person within seconds *fully* by turning entire body into black coal. When Hartley picked Obelisk in the first episode of season 2 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, why was only her hand affected and why was Obelisk killing her slowly.. slow enough that Hunter was able to cut the hand? Is this an obvious plot hole which everyone failed to notice? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: my guess, it's an obvious plot hole that we all picked up on but wrote off in the name of dramatic tension, but there may be more to it, stay tuned...

Comment: I would guess the Diviner kills different people differently: holding an Infinity Stone will kill you instantly as well (like the housekeeper girl of the Collector), but depending on your own strength/willpower/whatever, it might take longer (Ronan held it for a bit before smashing it into his hammer, as did Peter).

Comment: @BMWurm Obelisk isn't an Infinity Stone.

Comment: I don't the he was saying it is, just comparing it to one.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I know, they are even **more** powerful, so no wonder something the Kree created is less deadly than something that survived the Big Bang.

Comment: @KSmarts That's what I am saying.. One can't compare an Infinity Stone with ordinary artifacts. Everything has different properties.

Answer (score 1):

Remind me again when the obelisk ever killed someone instantly?

I'm pretty sure the weapons that hydra created to duplicate its coalifying (I'm sorry) ability killed quickly, but they were designed for that. The impression that Raina gave me was that the diviner was a judge. It seems to grant the power it holds to humans with Inhuman genetics without a fight, but I think it might subject regular humans to a lethal test. Maybe a genetic examination. Maybe some it kills out of hand, and others must... Struggle with it?  This is all just guesswork, but maybe someone like captain America with his "physically perfect human specimen" genetics would be able to hold it, or at least survive whatever killed that agent the OP referred to. (Can't remember her name)

Comment: S02E08: The Things We Bury. It opens with Whitehall making a guy touch the diviner and he instantly* (within seconds) gets coalified. Then Skye's mom comes out and touches it, and is not coalified.

Comment: Fair enough. I had a feeling I was forgetting something.  Still. According to my answer that guy would be someone that the diviner didn't even test, just judged as genetically inferior and killed out of hand

Comment: Sure, not arguing that. Just providing an example as you requested.

Comment: Also the one used to kill Olmos' character (I forgot his name) was said to be the (failed) result of trying to make them non-lethal, but it still killed him quickly. And Triplett (sp?) was also killed instantly by a shard.

Comment: SPOILER: It affected Coulson slowly enough for his hand to be cut off without it reaching the rest of his arm as well. It also waited a moment before affecting him. Though it still appeared to be faster than than when Izzy touched it.